# Set value for the whole day if condtion applies only to two hours

Tags: r, if-statement

**Edit:** I have found a solution without the usage of additional packages. Still, thanks to those who gave an answer.

```
for (Z in 1:nrow(MyData)) {Today= substr(MyData[Z,1], 1, 10)
  if(any(MyData$Rain[((MyData$Time>= strptime(paste(Today, "06:30:00", sep = " "),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))&
                 (MyData$Time<= strptime(paste(Today, "09:00:00", sep = " "),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))]>0)) {MyData$Rain_Binary[(MyData$Time>=strptime(paste(Today, "06:30:00", sep = " "),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))&
                                                                                                                                       (MyData$Time<= strptime(paste(Today, "20:00:00", sep = " "),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))]=1
  }
}
```

I have a dataframe like this:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-05-05 06:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end   <- as.POSIXct("2015-05-07 20:00:00", format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Time=seq.POSIXt(start, end, by="10 min")

MyData=data.frame(Time=Time,Rain=rep(0,(length(Time))),Rain_Binary=rep(0,(length(Time))))
MyData[c(2:4,154:157,324:328),2]=5
```

I'd like to set the value in the Rain_Binary-column to 1 if it rained during that time:

```
Limit=c(substr(MyData$Time[MyData$Time>= strptime("2015-05-05 06:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") & MyData$Time <= strptime("2015-05-05 09:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")],12,19))

MyData$Rain_Binary=with(MyData, ifelse(((MyData$Rain>0) &  (substr(MyData$Time,12,19) %in% Limit)), 1, 0))
```

This works as intended.
My problem is now that I'd like to set the value to 1 for the WHOLE day if it rained during the time specified in Limit and not only during the specified time.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`group_by` the date and use `any`.

```
library('tidyverse')

MyData %>%
  group_by(as.Date(Time)) %>%
  mutate(Rain_Binary = any(Rain_Binary))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `data.table` and `lubridate`. Let's say your data.frame has only two columns (`Rain` and `Time`) and you have a function that takes in `Time` and `rain` and outputs a binary number based on if the criteria is met or not, called `func_rain`.

```
library(data.table)
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-05-05 06:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end   <- as.POSIXct("2015-05-07 20:00:00", format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt=data.table(Time=seq.POSIXt(start, end,length.out = 300),
              Rain=round(runif(300)*2))

rain_func <- function(Rain, Time){
  st <- as.POSIXct("2015-05-05 06:30:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  et <- as.POSIXct("2015-05-05 9:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  ifelse(Time >= st & Time <= et, 1, 0)
}

dt[, newval := rain_func(Rain, Time)][, dayval := any(newval), by = lubridate::round_date(Time, "1 day")]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> dt
                    Time Rain newval dayval
  1: 2015-05-05 06:00:00    1      0   TRUE
  2: 2015-05-05 06:12:26    0      0   TRUE
  3: 2015-05-05 06:24:52    2      0   TRUE
  4: 2015-05-05 06:37:19    2      1   TRUE
  5: 2015-05-05 06:49:45    0      1   TRUE
 ---                                       
296: 2015-05-07 19:10:14    2      0  FALSE
297: 2015-05-07 19:22:40    0      0  FALSE
298: 2015-05-07 19:35:07    0      0  FALSE
299: 2015-05-07 19:47:33    0      0  FALSE
300: 2015-05-07 20:00:00    2      0  FALSE
```

The function is used to create a binary value for the given time interval based on your logic and then uses chaining to set the value for the day.

Using a function instead of hard coded `if else` statements makes it easier to apply those on multiple columns/datasets and `round_date` is quite useful when you're looking at odd intervals e.g. `round_date(Time, "37 min")`.

Comment: I've specified for `func_rain` now `func_rain=function(R, Z){ifelse(((R>0) &  (substr(Z,12,19) %in% Limit)),  1, 0)
}` . Executing the `dt` code you wrote gives an error: `Error in `[.data.table`(dt[, `:=`(newval, func_rain(MyData$Rain, MyData$Time))],  : 
  Type of RHS ('logical') must match LHS ('double').`  and `In addition: Warning message: In any(newval) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical` I've never worked with this package before, what did I do wrong?

Comment: you don't need to use `MyData$Rain` there - `data.table` works with the column names directly i.e. use `func_rain(Rain, Time)` as in the example.

Comment: Still gives the same error:  `Error in ``[.data.table``(dt[, `:=`(newval, func_rain(Rain, Time))], , `:=`(Rain_Binary,  : 
  Type of RHS ('logical') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In any(newval) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical`

Comment: There was a syntax problem in what you wrote. I've edited my answer to add a `rain_func` to show how the code works. There will be some warnings when `any` tries to convert a double to a logical but those can be ignored since in your case getting `newval > 0` one or more times during the day means the same value for `dayval` i.e. 1. Alternatively, instead of `any(newval)` you could use `sum(newval)` and then filter for the days when `dayval > 0`.

Comment: Basically, it works as intended, although your `rain_func` now only adresses the first day in the `dt` table, and the new column `dayval`is only filled with `TRUE` until 12:00 at the first day. `rain_func <- function(Rain, Time){
  ifelse(((substr(Time,12,19) %in% Limit)&(Rain>0)), 1, 0)
}` gives the right values in `newval`, but also not the right ones in `dayval`.